# Does the damage of an equipped weapon affect spell damage?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I noticed that different Quarterstaves have different damage amounts listed. I understand weapon damage affects how much damage physical attacks do, but how does it work for magical classes like Sorcerer that usually use spells instead of attacking directly? Does the damage range on my equipped weapon (a Quarterstaff) effect how much damage my spells do?

[image: Comparing damage on two quarterstaves]

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? don't really see what you are asking.

Comment: @A.bakker If I cast a spell, is the amount of damage the spell does affected by the amount of damage listed on my equipped weapon?

Comment: o no, the damage from weapons don't effect spells

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put simply, no.

Spell damage is calculated based on the dice shown on the spell - see this example from the Baldur's Gate wiki. A fireball will do 8d6 damage (increased based on upcasting) irrespective of the weapon you're holding.

[image]
(source: https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Fireball )

The dice you're looking at on a weapon relate strictly to the damage done with melee or ranged attacks with that weapon (and will be affected by strength / dexterity as with other weapons.) Some weapons, like the Mourning Frost, add additional melee damage, but this has no direct effect on spell damage. A spell is not a weapon attack and therefore has its own damage dice.

Notably, there are certain weapons that will have *indirect* effects on spells - such as  the [Spellsparkler](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/The_Spellsparkler) which grants you lightning charges on a successful cast. In fact, the Mourning Frost you linked has a special effect that deals 1 additional cold damage, and this is triggered on the caster *dealing cold damage* by any means, and affects cold damage from any source, including a spell.

Comment: Some spells do deal weapon damage as part of their damage, Paladin Smite spells and Ranger's Ensnaring Shot for example.  Way of the Four Elements Monks also apply their unarmed damage to some of their spells.